# Number of conjugacy classes of elements of order $7$ in a group of order 168

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Let $G$ be a simple group of order $168$ (Here, we don't assume we know there is a unique such group). Compute the number of conjugacy classes of elements of order $7$ in $G$ [Hint: Consider Sylow $3$-subgroup].

I already proved that $n_7 =8$ so there are total $48$ many order $7$ elements in $G$. As hint suggested, I considered Sylow $3$-subgroup. First, I think I can't determine $n_3$ nor $n_2$. Any idea for this problem?

Comment: I'm off to work, so I'll answer later if I remember. My hint for you right now is that the prime factorization of $168$ is $2^3\cdot3\cdot7$.

Comment: @integer It'll be more helpful if you give more hints :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints.

1. Since $n_7=8$ we have $|G:N_G(P_7)|=8$ and $|N_G(P_7)|=21$.
2. There are exactly two conjugacy classes of elements of order $7$ in group $H=N_G(P_7)$.
3. Elements of order $7$ from different conjugacy classes of group $H$ are not conjugate in group $G$.

Comment: A very well structured hint in my opinion.

Comment: I wonder if 2. is true because $|H| = 21$ so by orbit-stabilizer, the size of each conjugacy classes divide $21$.

Comment: If $a\in P_7$ then $|a^H|=|H:C_H(a)|=|H|/|C_H(a)|=21/7=3$.
If $b\in P_7$ and $b\notin a^H$ then similarly $|b^H|=3$. Now we have $P_7=a^H\cup b^H\cup\{e\}$.

Comment: I've never seen the notation $a^H$ but it seems it stands for conjugacy class of $a$ in $H$. How do you know $|C_H(a)| = 7$?

Comment: If $C_H(a)=H$, then $n_3=|G:N_G(P_3)|\leq 8$. So $n_3=4$, which is impossible because $G$ is a simple group.

Comment: @kabenyuk I don't get it. $n_3\leq 8$ then $n_3$ can be $4$ or $7$ and none of them are $1$ (so not normal). I don't know why it contradicts the fact that $G$ is simple.

Comment: Since $|G|=|N_G(P_3)|\cdot|G:N_G(P_3)|$ and $P_7<N_G(P_3)$, it follows that index $|G:N_G(P_3)|$ does not divide by 7. So still $n_3=4$. Think about why this is impossible for a simple group. You may also notice that in this case $|G:N_G(P_3)|=4$, i.e. group $G$ has a subgroup of a small index, this is also impossible for a simple group.

Comment: @kabenyuk The number of conjugacy classes of elements of order $7$ in $G$ is just $2$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.